# Joomla 1.5.14 to Joomla 3.0 Migration

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla1.5, updates, joomla3.0

We have already  Joomla´s version 1.5.14 from 2009 to make our homepage setting. Now we want to upgrade the version to 3.0.

We have made a test page 3.0 and compared it with our original page. We understand that files and the database have been subject to changes, so it´s difficult for us to see how we can practically move our data to the new version.

We have discovered that with regard to the version 1.7 it is pretty easy to upgrade to the new version.  We have studied your Joomla manual, but we still have problems to get it right.  Have you ever yourselves tried to upgrade a similar situation?

Can you possibly give us some hints how to do it?
It would help us if you could suggest the steps you want us to take?
You now, it´s not so nice to go through a huge number of manual pages. 
As you can appreciate I have taken back-up on the data base and the files. I´ve come that far and need your help to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fear not, upgrading from Joomla 1.5 to 3.0 isn't hard at all. There are 2 really good extensions that allow you to do this:

[jUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658) and [SP Upgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609).

Both allow you to upgrade to either Joomla 2.5 or 3.0

I would first recommend updating to the latest release of the 1.5 series (1.5.26) before using one of the extensions. To do this, simply download [this](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16891/73384/Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package.zip) package, upload to the root of your Joomla site in the FTP and extract it.

May I just point out that Joomla 2.5 is still the recommended version to use as it is the long term version, where as Joomla 3.0 is short term till Joomla 3.5 is released.

Comment: I did one of these the other day.

If you are migrating you might as well go to 3 unless you need a specific extension not supporting 3. 3 Is just 2.5 with responsive core outputs and new templates.

I definitely agree about updating to the current version first of 1.5 first.

Comment: I personally would stick with 2.5 till 3.5 comes as, as 2.5 is the recommended version to have, as it's long terms, whereas 3.o is shot term.

Comment: The main reason I wouldn't upgrade to 3.0 is the fact that major component updates are coming. Hence JModelLegacy etc are being used in components for J3.0. Presumably in either J3.1 or 3.5 there will be a new set of component controllers which will mean major changes will be required!

Comment: be cautious with using update plugins if you have made changes to the core tables in your database. unknown fieldnames/columns won't migrate

Comment: true true. one of the reasons why I always say to people that editing core files is a bad idea :)

Comment: @Lodder Do you have a link to jUpgrade or SP Upgrade "FREE Version"? It's look like i have to pay for it.