# Manually import Joomla K2 items from 1.5 to 3.0

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-k2

I have had a really tough time upgrading from Joomla 1.5 so I have decided to rebuild a clients mess of a site in 3.0 and start fresh and clean. There is a ton of K2 items I'd rather export and import into the new db. I have successfully exported the data to sql file, swapped out the table name, and imported the data in the new db. Problem is the content does not show up on the front or back-end...? What am I missing here? I am thinking this is a relational db issue and there is more to displaying this content.. Does anyone know the internals of k2 and what I need to do to get this content over? I'm really not trying to do this manually.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the similar thread here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320255/joomla-1-5-14-to-joomla-3-0-migration][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320255/joomla-1-5-14-to-joomla-3-0-migration

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to upgrade to joomla 2.5 at first. Use this extension called JUpgrade http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658

I tried it my self and it worked fine for me (j1.5 k2 2.4.1)

Comment: Yea I tried that way too many times. The site apparently uses so many plugins that alter too many tables for jupgrade to work. I have resorted to hacking up the db and piecing it back together. I decided to just start fresh with 3.0 and bring over what I could. This involves a whole overhaul of plugins used and design.

Comment: also have you checked table prefix? "var $dbprefix = 'jos_';" in configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to install your K2-content on a fresh Joomla 3, make sure to import the old user-tables first - I used redMigrate (former JUpgrade) for this (and only for this...). The K2-items from your database you export on the old site and import on the new one. Look for categories and items to have access set on 1.

Have a look here: [K2 help site](http://getk2.org/community/English-K2-Community/164647-Joomla-15-to-30)